# Sitecore 9 LinkManager.GetItemUrl how to get a custom Url?

Tags: sitecore, deprecated, sitecore9

We upgrade Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3.
In Sitecore 8.2 we use a custom-LinkProvider and LinkManager.GetItemUrl(...) returns a custom url for items in the global-repository. 
Now with Sitecore 9.3 we don't use any more the custom-LinkProvider because it is deprecated.

What is the alternative for a custom linkprovider?

Example: 
Sitecore 8 returns https://test.com/selection/one/mySubject with LinkManager.GetItemUrl(...)
now with Sitecore 9 it returns https://test.com/sitecore/content/test/global-repository/data/2020/test/one/mySubject

Answer (score 0):

We just solve the problem with the itemUrlBuilder configuration in Sitecore.config.
We use a custom itemUrlBuilder 
 that overide the Build() from the ItemUrlBuilder and implement us custom code.